# How we know some action is performed in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

hi I want to get the response of actions performed in the windows phone, such as user is answered the call, calling another usr, sms recived etc. In android there is Intent Filters and Broadcast recivers for catching any news happening in the phone. Do we have same mechanism in Windows phone?

Comment: What does the official documentation have to say about that?

Comment: No, Idea I am still searching for it. For some security reason WP is banned the backTasks, so I am afraid that this too not available for us. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can't intercept those events from your app with the current SDK.

Comment: @Renan - Haha, I'm not *that* lazy with my answers! :D